# Firebase test lab: Failed to create a test matrix

Tags: firebase-test-lab

I tried to upload my app to test lab and it seems not working. I always got an error like **Failed to create a test matrix.**

Anyone can run the test lab please let me know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something you should submit to Firebase Support for help.